# Adding an object across multiple objects

Tags: graphics

To add Arrow connecting the red point across two Show[] function result as below, Could I know how to modify my code?

```
trialSet = {1, 4, 5};
sampleMean = Mean[trialSet];
Column[
 {(*Upper Graph *)
  Show[ListPlot[{Transpose[{trialSet, 
       ConstantArray[0, 3]}], {Style[{Mean[trialSet], 0}, Red, 
       PointSize @ .06]} } , PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.04}    , 
    PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, Axes -> {True, True}],
   Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -6, 6}, 
    PlotRange -> Full]],
  (*Lower Graph*)
  Show[Histogram[{sampleMean}, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}], 
   NumberLinePlot[Style[sampleMean, Red], {x, -6, 6}, Spacings -> 0], 
   Axes -> {True, False}]}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easier way is to use single graphics canvas (combining various graphics objects with `Show` and/or adding desired primitives as `Epilog` or `Prolog`):

```
 nlp = NumberLinePlot[
    {Style[sampleMean, Red], 
     {trialSet, Style[sampleMean, Red]}},
   {x, -6, 6},
   Spacings -> {0, 1.05}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[{sampleMean}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, 
  Epilog -> 
   {First @ nlp,
    Red, Thick, Arrowheads @ Medium, 
    Arrow[{{sampleMean, 1.05}, {sampleMean, 0}}, .025]}, 
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
ug = Show[
   ListPlot[{Transpose[{trialSet, ConstantArray[0, 3]}], 
       {{Mean[trialSet], 0}}},
     PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, 
     PlotMarkers -> {{Automatic, 0.2}, {Automatic, .3}}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 1/2}}, 
     Axes -> True], 
   Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -6, 6}], 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, .1}, {0, 0}},
   ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {20, 2}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/6];

Histogram[{sampleMean}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, Automatic}, 
 Epilog -> 
   {Inset[ug, Scaled @ {0, 1.1}, Scaled @ {0, 0}, Scaled[1]], 
    Red, Thick, Arrowheads @ Medium, PointSize @ Large, 
    Point @ {sampleMean, 0}
    Arrow[{{sampleMean, 1.1}, {sampleMean, 0}}, .025]}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, .1}, {0, 0}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {50, 100}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! Could I have additional question? If there is a more combined graph at upper area as picture  above,-I've just edited original question-,how to fix my code?

Comment: @Soon, please see the update.